# Pairing a bluetooth Magic trackpad

Tags: magic-trackpad

I am attempting to pair the magic trackpad with a macbook.  The MB has bluetooth enabled and the "Setup bluetooth trackpad" is invoked:

[image: Trackpad pairing screen]

As can be seen here the pairing is not successful.

On the trackpad side: I have tried pressing the power button a number of times. The behavior is the trackpad light goes green for about two to three seconds then turns off.

Is that the normal behavior for the trackpad? Or is there something else missing in the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: the batteries were ***weak*** .. but *not* ***dead***. Thus the intermittent green light (but non functionality).